# DNN: HTML editor not showing the folders to select an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, dotnetnuke, rich-text-editor

I am new to dotnetnuke and i am facing problem when i want to insert an image to my page. I have used HTML editor for that. I have given the edit right to some users. But now problem is when they edit the page and then go to the edit content menu it will open the Rich Text editor. But when they try to insert image through image manager they are not able to see any path or any folders over there. And same thing can do Admin.
Here is my code:

```
                    <dotnetnuke>
<htmlEditor defaultProvider="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider" />
  </providers>
</htmlEditor>
<navigationControl defaultProvider="DNNMenuNavigationProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNDropDownNavigationProvider\" />
    <add name="ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\ASP2MenuNavigationProvider\" />
    <add name="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNMenuNavigationProvider\" />
    <add name="DNNTreeNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNTreeNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNTreeNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNTreeNavigationProvider\" />
    <add name="SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\SolpartMenuNavigationProvider\" />
  </providers>
</navigationControl>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue here...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..I resolved this issue with following steps. First  login with host account then go to host settings. Click on file manager. If you file manager is empty then Add file manager module at that place and sync the folders and save it. Then you will be able to select an image from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

We host lots of DNN sites and I saw this issue on only 2 of those sites and I haven't had any luck in determining why it occurred with those 2 sites and not any others. I do know the issue actually involves something with the Telerik RAD Editor. The only solution I've been able to find after many hours of looking is to switch to the CKEditor instead. This is slated to become the default editor for DNN in the future anyway and is quite nice now. https://dnnckeditor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this and it was caused by invalid characters in a filename in the folder that was not showing up in image manager. If I remember correctly it happened with "(", ")", and "'". Once I removed those characters from the file names and told DNN to resync the folders then the missing folders and files appeared.

Comment: But in my case admin can show that folders and same thing user cant access it.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this was caused by a missing directory portal, which I detected by comparing the backups with the production application. Introducing a new folder solved the problem.

Comment: Please consider translating your comment to english as it's the main language used on SO. Using a single language makes it possible for everyone to understand questions, answers and delivers help to a wider range of people.